# How to set number of hits of a url to get cached in Flask-Cache?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, http-caching, flask-cache

Flask-cache by default stores the second request if it comes within given time-period. It won't maintain the first request. 
For reference, I checked with nginix, nginix saves the fifth request. I got a argument maintaining the same informtion.

```
proxy_cache_min_uses 5;
```

Is there any same argument available in flask-cache? Or I just change the default number of hits to store the url?